# MS Word insists on proofing in French

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

MS Word insists on proofing my entirely English document partly in French. Any word similar to a French word (e.g.: regional/régionale) is marked as incorrectly spelled. And when I right-click these red-underlined words, instead of "spellling" the menu entry is <>. I've removed French as an available language and unchecked the French dictionary (both in Options), but the behavior persists.

Windows input language is set to English (was when it first occurred, and I have since also removed the option for French as an input language).

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting all of the text in your document and setting the proofing language *for that text.*

Turn off the option to Automatically Detect Language. Word is not very good at this.

### See [my Article "Proofing Language Keeps Changing - Solutions"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b).

This is on the Microsoft Community Answers forum for Word.

The key concept is that the proofing language is set at the character level in a Word document and can be pasted into the document with text.

Some of the article's macros were posted here in answer [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1587514/rapidly-switching-proofing-language-in-microsoft-word/1587667#1587667).